# Sumifs with Array conditional

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm surprised I can't find this anywhere which makes me think I must be going about this incorrectly.  I want to be able to include a series of values within sumifs so it performs like a loop for each value in the conditional (without having to write a " +sumifs(....) for each value.  Here's an example of what I have so far that is not working

```
`=SUMIFS(Sum,Range1,Criteria1, '[Stores.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H, "Store #"&Regions!$T:$T&"*")`
```

So I'm trying to pass every value in Regions!T:T as a criteria.
For example "Store #150 Los Angeles" and "Store #155 San Diego" would both need to be passed through the argument.  Currently the formula just returns the first item it matches and doesn't continue to the next item.
I hope that makes sense.  Please ask if you need more clarity.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?  I'm assuming you're copying the formula into a column with the same number of rows as column T?

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I am getting only the first matching value.  In this case I would get the result for Store #150 but not Store #155.
I am not using the same number of columns as I am trying to add up all matching stores on one column.  The only option I see is to write the code as 
`=SUMIFS(Sum,Range1,Criteria1, '[Stores.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H, "Store #"&Regions!$T3&"*")+ SUMIFS(Sum,Range1,Criteria1, '[Stores.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H, "Store #"&Regions!$T4&"*")`
etc.. but there are 40 different rows that I would have to do that with.

Comment: I am certain there's a way to do it using formulas, but I'm not sure what that would be.  It might be easier to do it using a VBA function which loops over the range.  What are the values for Sum, Range1, and Criteria1?

Comment: '=SUMIFS('[QB Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$L:$L,'[QB Data .xlsx]Sheet1'!$I:$I,E16,'[QB Data.xlsx]Sheet1'!$H:$H, "Store #"&Regions!$T:$T&"*")'
Here Sheet1!L:L is the dollar amount on the invoice, Sheet1!I:I is the item number and T is the name of the store.  The Regions!T:T is the list of numbers for the stores to match (150 on one row, 155 on another etc)
Again thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not coming up with anything as of yet, I'll look it over more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to start an "intermediate" column next to the T column, do a `sumifs` for each of the rows of that column, and then sum that column into another cell.  Tables or even just array sums may also be helpful here.

I came up with the following in VBA, but I cannot test it completely:

```
Option Explicit
Function SumSumIfs(ByVal inp As Range) As Integer

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim QBData As Worksheet
    Dim Stores As Worksheet

    Set QBData = Workbooks.Open("QBData.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Stores = Workbooks.Open("Stores.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim QBRange1, QBRange2, SalesRange As Range

    Set QBRange1 = QBData.Range("H1:H" & Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set QBRange2 = QBData.Range("I1:I" & Range("I1").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set SalesRange = QBData.Range("H1:H" & QBData.Range("H1").End(xlDown).Row)


    For i = 1 To inp.End(xlDown).Row
      SumSumIfs = SumSumIfs + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(QBRange1, QBRange2, _
                  "=" & Stores.Cells(16, 5), StoreRange3, "=" & inp.Cells(i, 19))
    Next i

End Function
```

Again, I'm certain there's a way to do this looping with the formula, but searching around, it was not evident to me.

Comment: It didn't directly solve my problem but I did decide to solve my problem in VBA.  Thank you for your time dedicated to helping me.